# ColdFusion CFHTTP Call To Create Google Calendar Event

Tags: http, curl, coldfusion, google-calendar-api, coldfusion-10

I have implement most of the API calls using CFHTTP All is working fine. 
I am using below code to create google calendar event. 
Every parameter passed to it correct (validated). but with cfhttp it is not getting sent. 
I got error of Filecontent

```
{ "error": 
  { "errors": [ 
      { "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required", 
        "message": "Missing end time."
      } ], 
"code": 400, "message": "Missing end time." 
  }
}
```

**Code**

```
<cfset title=eventTitle>
    <cfset curlPost = StructNew()>
    <cfset curlPost['summary'] = eventTitle>
    <cfif eventType EQ 'FIXED-TIME'>
        <cfset startTime = Replace(eventStartTime," ","T") & ":00">
        <cfset endTime = Replace(eventEndTime," ","T") & ":00">
        <cfset eventDate = "">
        <cfset allDay = 0>

        <cfset curlPost['start']['dateTime'] = startTime>
        <cfset curlPost['start']['timeZone'] = data.value>
        <cfset curlPost['end']['dateTime'] = endTime>
        <cfset curlPost['end']['timeZone'] = data.value>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset startTime = "">
        <cfset endTime = "">
        <cfset eventDate = eventDate>
        <cfset allDay = 1>

        <cfset curlPost['start']['date'] = eventDate>
        <cfset curlPost['end']['date'] = eventDate>
    </cfif>

    <cfdump var="#serializeJSON(curlPost)#">
    <cfdump var="#curlPost#">

    <cfhttp url="https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events" method="post" result="httpResponse">          
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content_Type" value="application/json">    
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #session.access_token#" /> 
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(curlPost)#"> 
    </cfhttp>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but I notice `method=post` in your cfhttp tag.  That's normally associated with forms and you are not submitting any form fields.

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is formatted correctly?  ...https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/565 this guy got a similar error from malformed JSON

Comment: I noticed in your `<cfelse>` you set `endTime` but it's not getting set in your `curlPost` object.

Comment: The content header name looks wrong. It should be `name="Content-Type"` (with dash) instead of `name="Content_Type"` (with underscore).

Comment: If fixing the header name resolves it, I'd vote to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535563/missing-end-time-with-google-calendar-and-racket-google-package?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Ageax. (name="Content-Type" (with dash) instead of name="Content_Type") resolved issue. Thanks a lot. Yes you can close it and mark as duplicate

Comment: Glad it resolved the issue!  Voted to mark as duplicate done ["Missing End Time" with Google Calendar and Racket Google Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535563/missing-end-time-with-google-calendar-and-racket-google-package)